# How to ensure that check_SCRIPTS are added to the distribution?

Tags: autotools, automake

I realized that the python scripts that I used for testing

```
check_SCRIPTS = mypython.py
TESTS = mypython.py
```

are not included in the distribution. I found while running `make distcheck`. Which means that `make check` fails on the distribution.

What is the canonical way to add the `check_SCRIPTS` to the distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Scripts section of the GNU Automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html) scripts are not distributed by default.

You can add them to the distribution using the generic

```
EXTRA_DIST = $(check_SCRIPTS)
```

or by prefixing `check_SCRIPTS` with `dist_` like so:

```
dist_check_SCRIPTS = mypython.py
```